# Why is operator!= synthesized from operator==, but not the other way around?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, comparison-operators

In c++20, if I provide an `operator==` for a type, then the compiler synthesizes an `operator!=`, but not the other way around.

Here's some [code](https://godbolt.org/z/Gf754E):

```
struct A {};
bool operator==(A const&, A const&); 

struct B {};
bool operator!=(B const&, B const&); 

int main()
{
    if (A{} != A{}) {}  // error in c++17 
                        // ok in c++20

    if (B{} == B{}) {}  // error in c++17 
                        // error in c++20, why?
}
```

This seems inconsistent, since `!=` and `==` are required to be contrary, and if one can be synthesized from the other, then the inverse should work too. What is the reason for this?

Comment: Here == and != are two entirely different operators. Consequently their operations are not inverse unless you define them to be inverses.

Comment: @OS2 - Except they *are* implicitly inverses under C++20.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because this adds complexity to the language for no benefit.

The primary operation is equality. C++20 lets you just define `operator==` to get the full complement of equality operations (`==` and `!=`). Likewise, the primary ordering operation is `<=>` and C++20 lets you just define that and get the full complement of ordering operators (`<`, `<=`, `>`, and `>=`).

There's no reason to add arbitrary extra flexibility here. Why would you *just* implement `operator!=` when you could *just* implement `operator==`?

---

The language currently has a nice symmetry between `==` and `<=>` that I think is valuable and important, from the perspective of understanding the rules and building functionality. While you *could* define `x == y` as `not (x != y)` - that seems inherently strange to me since the name of the "not equals" is... not "equals", but you could do that. But you definitely wouldn't want to define `x <=> y` in terms of `x < y` or `x <= y`. That would be an expensive transformation that couldn't even determine the comparison category properly. So such a direction would break the symmetry with ordering that we have, making the language rules harder to understand.

Comment: Well, I would have thought consistency is a benefit. Is this a lot of additional complexity to add?

Comment: @cigien I don't think actually think of this as consistency - I think the important consistency is between `==` and `<=>` here.

Comment: Isn't `!=` and `==` required to be opposite? I thought it's UB otherwise, so there is some consistency required here.

Comment: @cigien So... just write `==`?

Comment: @cigien Having the consistency of all programs implement the operators by only implementing `==` rather than some programs implementing it with `!=` is a benefit.

Comment: @eerorika Yes, that does make sense.

Comment: Yes, I definitely agree that `<=>` shouldn't be defined in terms of `<` or anything, but it seemed that `==` in terms of `!=` would be straightforward. But I suppose there's nothing to be gained by adding that.

Comment: @cigien No, `!=` and `==` can do completely different things; one could print, the other could format your hard drive.  It is allowed that either return `void` or anything else.  Now, a lot of code may rely on it doing the opposite (a LOT of code), but the C++ language itself (outside of the standard library) places no such constraints.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont That's interesting. Now that `!=` can be synthesized I thought not writing it as opposite to `==` would invoke UB.

Comment: @cigien If you pass such a type into a function template constrained on `equality_comparable`, then you're violating the semantic constraints of that concept and that would be library UB. But it's never language UB, no.

Comment: @Barry Ah, ok. So this [program](https://godbolt.org/z/qbfa49) is well-formed, and will return 0 even though `f` and `g` have identical definitions?

Comment: @cigien Yes that's well-formed.